# Сборка System.Windows пустая, но почему?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Пытаюсь использовать тип Clipboard из пространства имен System.Windows, однако, оно пустое (на скрине видно, что оно развернуто, но там ничего нет). Также на скрине справа видно, что я добавил в зависимости System.Windows. На втором скрине показано, что я указал using System.Windows, однако, Clipboard мне все равно не доступен.

Тип проекта: консольное приложение

Фреймворк: проблема наблюдается на .NET Core 3.1, .NET Core 5.0, .NET Framework 4.7.2

Установелнные рабочие нагрузки: разработка классических приложений Windows

[image: окно visual studio]

[image: Clipboard не распознан]

Comment: Есть разные классы `Clipboard`. [Один](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=net-5.0) в сборке PresentationCore.dll (пространство имён System.Windows), [другой](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard?view=net-5.0) - в сборке System.Windows.Forms.dll (пространство имён System.Windows.Forms). Для использования первого вы не подключили сборку, для второго - не открыли пространство имён.

Comment: "Для использования первого вы не подключили сборку" - подключил, на скрине справа видно даже

Comment: Студия ведь сама предлагает исправить проблемы: и сборки подключит, и пространства имён добавит. Только нажмите указанную комбинацию клавиш (или мышкой ткните).

Comment: Сборка `PresentationCore.dll`

Comment: Главное: ваше приложение какого типа? WinForms, WPF, Console, Xamarin, что-то другое? Во многих типах приложений есть свои собственные классы Clipboard (в Замарине тоже есть).

Comment: а, понятно. Я подключил просто System.Windows. Сейчас подключил PresentationCode.dll - заработало, спасибо

Comment: у меня консольное приложеие

Answer (score 1):

PS: как подсказали выше, нужно было подключать PresentationCore.dll. Вопрос закрываю.